# KeyWindow NavigationController is null when modal is open after iOS 14.2 Update

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

After iOS 14.2 update on Xamarin, the `UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.NavigationController` is null when a popup message(modal) is open.

I am trying to PopToRoot, but I am not able to due to this bug, since NavigationController for the KeyWindow is null. Anyone having the same issue or know a work around for it?

This is only happening on iOS 14.2, it is working on iOS 14.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't even have this property on my KeyWindow (iOS 14.2) and would recommend going with `RootViewController`, case it to the controller type you actually have as the root (most likely `UINavigationViewController`) and that will be your reference, based on your project architecture (on how you build you UI):

[image]

**Better approach #1:** implement a navigation service which will hold the reference to your UINavigrationController and whenever navigation is desired, you resolve the service via IoC and execute required methods.

**Better approach #2:** switch to Xamarin.Forms and Shell navigation where all this stuff is already handled and provided to you as navigation service.